# Jquery reload vs Press enter on Address bar

Tags: jquery, css, macos, google-chrome, webkit

I'm using some jquery functions to align the elements on my page and not just css.
On firefox it works perfectly.
On chrome (under mac os x) i have some weird problem.

If i just type on the URL Bar the address and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it runs ok.
If i do a command + r (same thing as using ctrl + r) it dont runs the jquery align.

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the second image, the position is messed. if i go and just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> with the address bar selected, or resize... so it runs the jquery again, it fix the positions.

Is there a way to force to run the $(document).ready().

I don't know why it is happening, i tried to put the script on the end of the html with and without the $(document).ready(), in the beginning of the file i already uses $(document).ready().

It seems to be an problem with the web-kit as the safari have the same problem.

I noticed one thing:

If i put an alert on the page. If i do a command + r the alert appears before the images loads.
If i press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the Address bar the alert appears after.
So it seems the jquery $(document).ready() runs after the images are loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixes it with

```
$(window).load
```

It seems the $(window).load waits for the images to be loaded.